# Forbidden error when calling Microsoft Graph from Java Application using Application ID

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

List SCOPES = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
final ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
.clientId(applicationId)
.clientSecret(secret)
.tenantId(tenantId)
.build();
final TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider_new = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(SCOPES, credential);

```
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
            .builder()
            .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .buildClient();

    graphClient.users().buildRequest().get();
```

With

compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-spring-boot', version: '2.3.5'

```
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '28.2-jre'

compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-identity', version: '1.2.5'
compile group: 'com.microsoft.graph', name: 'microsoft-graph', version: '3.5.0'
```

I've added all the necessary permissions to the application, and it's been consented in Active Directory, but same response.

It works using this code, after I sign in with a user account:
final DeviceCodeCredential credential1 = new DeviceCodeCredentialBuilder()
.clientId(applicationId)
.challengeConsumer(challenge -> System.out.println(challenge.getMessage()))
.build();

But I want to use ClientSecretCredential and use the client secret, not create a challenge.

Update: The error message I get is

```
SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Error message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
SdkVersion : graph-java/v3.5.0


403 : Forbidden
```

[Here's a link of the permissions the app has in API Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdMkS.png)

I also have the following permissions to Azure Rights Management Services in case it helps
Application.Read.All, Content.DelegatedReader, Content.SuperUser

Comment: Can you please add the operation detail that you are trying to perform like get users etc. And what are the application api permissions you have added for the service principal?

Comment: Also please add the full error details including request id and timestamp without personal information.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I've updated the question with those details.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your  granted permission  you missed the  `User.ReadWrite` and `User.ReadWrite.All`  Please add that permission  .

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

Comment: Excellent, that worked, yeah I had Delegated type permissions, but not Application. It's quite obvious now, but I didn't read anything about that in the docs. Thanks ShrutiJoshi-MT

Comment: If you have the Delegated permissions then  `User.ReadWrite` permission must be be added. For more information please refer the document mentioned in the answer.

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you